# The provider hashicorp/aws does not support resource type "aws_internet_gateway_attachment"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Why do I get this error with Terraform,

> The provider hashicorp/aws does not support resource type "aws_internet_gateway_attachment".

You can see the resource [`aws_internet_gateway_attachment` defined in the docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/internet_gateway_attachment). The full error is,

```
│ Error: Invalid resource type
│ 
│   on main.tf line 26, in resource "aws_internet_gateway_attachment" "example":
│   26: resource "aws_internet_gateway_attachment" "example" {
│ 
│ The provider hashicorp/aws does not support resource type "aws_internet_gateway_attachment".
╵
```

this is the hdl I'm using

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway_attachment" "example" {
  internet_gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  vpc_id              = aws_vpc.main.id
}
```

---

I'm using version 3.75.1 of the AWS provider.

Comment: Add some code, at least the lines in question and probably a few above and below it.

Comment: @kenlukas updated.

Comment: What version of the aws provider are you using?  It's possible that the resource you're attempting to use was released on a later version.

Comment: @kenlukas updated.

Comment: I don't see that resource for that version of the provider. Make sure that version is display at the top of the screen

Comment: Please update your provider version to use that resource definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terraform docs default to the lastest, version. The doc page you're looking at is,

> https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/internet_gateway_attachment#attributes-reference

What you want to do is replace that `latest` with the version you're using, in this case `3.75.1`. Like this,

> https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/3.75.1/docs/resources/internet_gateway_attachment#attributes-reference

That brings up a 404,

> This documentation page doesn't exist for version 3.75.1 of the aws provider.

Which basically means you must [upgrade the Terraform provider.](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/15967/18965)