# How do I upgrade or pin a Terraform Provider?

Tags: terraform, versioning

This is a follow-up to [The provider hashicorp/aws does not support resource type "aws_internet_gateway_attachment"](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/15954/the-provider-hashicorp-aws-does-not-support-resource-type-aws-internet-gateway).

The crux of it is, I'm using 3.75.1 of the AWS provider, and I need to upgrade. How do I do that?

I got the version by reading the `.terraform.lock.hcl`

```
provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" {
  version     = "3.75.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Upgrading to the newest version

You can upgrade the provider with

```sh
terraform init -upgrade
```

So long as you don't have the version specified anywhere in a `required_providers` block.

## Pinning with a `required_providers` block

You can pin or specify any [arbitrary version constraint](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/version-constraints) with a `required_providers` block, like this.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.14.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}
```

## Terraform pre 0.13

Prior to Terraform version 0.13, you could specify your version in the provider block,

```
provider "aws" {
  version = "4.14.0"
  region = "us-east-1"
}
```

---

Find the official docs at,

- [Lock and Upgrade Provider Versions: Upgrade the AWS provider version](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/provider-versioning#upgrade-the-aws-provider-version)
- [Provider Requirements](https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/requirements)